# linux ip aliasing

Tags: ip-aliasing

Do aliased ip addresses have to be on the same network?

E.g. If I have eth0 with 10.10.10.1, can I setup an alias (eth0:1) with ip address 10.10.11.1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

`ifconfig eth0:1 10.10.11.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`